# How to find relation of a table with different table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I my work environment we have lot of tables and there is mapping or relationship with each other.
I want to know the relationship of table with different table. I just used a query like `user_cons_columns` but i show only constraints of a table with `pk, fk` relationship. But here some table not having `referential constraint` but some columns having mapping key with another table.

Is there any way to find the relationship key, if table do not have `Referential relationship (pk, fk)`?

Note: Am using oracle 12c

Comment: One of the purposes of foreign keys is to explicitly define such relationships.  You should fix the data model so the desired relationships are explicit.

Comment: For use in the future - when I create a new table with an artificial primary key (i.e. a number obtained from a sequence) I name the primary key column something like `ID_NAME_OF_NEW_TABLE`. Any table which needs to have a foreign key reference back to that table gets a column named `ID_NAME_OF_NEW_TABLE` to serve as the foreign key. In this manner there's no ambiguity about the table to which each ID value refers. Sadly this doesn't help you with your current situation. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know data model (or know someone else who does), I don't see a way to do that.

Suppose all tables contain column named `ID`; how will you know whether some of them represent referential integrity (or not), if there's no such a constraint defined on those tables/columns?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, Thats the problem am having right now..

Answer (score 0):

In a simple case where you have `THIS_TABLE.ID` and `OTHER_TABLE.ID` and you want to know if there's an implicit relationship between them, I feel like the question to ask is: "Could you successfully create a FK between these columns without an error?" In other words, if your hypothesis is that all of the `ID`s in `THIS_TABLE` must exist in `OTHER_TABLE`, you can write a query to check that.

```
select count(b.id) / count(1) as perc_fk
from this_table a
left join other_table b
on b.id = a.id;
```

If you get 100% back, then you could create a FK without an error (and perhaps you should). If you get a high percentage like 99% back, you might still have a relationship, but the data is dirty (because you don't have a FK to keep it clean). If you get a lower percentage, like 60%, they probably aren't parent-child tables, but siblings which share a common parent. If you get 0%, they aren't related at all.

If you have a lot of tables to examine, you can semi-automate this process:

```
select case rownum when 1 then null else 'union all ' end ||
    'select ''' || table_name || ''' as t, count(b.' || column_name 
    || ') / count(1) as p from THIS_TABLE a left join ' || owner 
    || '.' || table_name || ' b on b.' || column_name || ' = a.ID' as sql
from all_tab_cols
where column_name like 'ID' and table_name <> 'THIS_TABLE';
```

The output will look like this:

```
select 'TABLE_A' as t, count(b.ID) / count(1) as p from THIS_TABLE a left join SCHEMA1.TABLE_A b on b.ID = a.id
union all select 'TABLE_B' as t, count(b.ID) / count(1) as p from THIS_TABLE a left join SCHEMA1.TABLE_B b on b.ID = a.id
union all select 'TABLE_C' as t, count(b.ID) / count(1) as p from THIS_TABLE a left join SCHEMA1.TABLE_C b on b.ID = a.id
```

Copy/paste it and run it, and you'll get something like:

```
T       P
TABLE_A 0
TABLE_B 0
TABLE_C 0.799276887183598
```

Which shows you that `TABLE_C.ID` has a potential relationship with `THIS_TABLE.ID`. But it's still up to you to investigate and decide whether to create a FK or not.

You could more fully automate this with a cartesian self-join on all_tab_cols, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to definitively determine relationships unless they were defined at the time the tables were created. Even if you were to establish PK/FK now based on column names and existing data, there's no guarantee that it is 100% accurate. Perhaps, although a long shot, you may want to review the design of how each of these tables are populated (dba_source might help) and try to define relationships as you go along.